# What are the new features of Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal)?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, stable-release-updates

Ubuntu 11.04 has been released.

Is it worth to upgrade?

My main usage is server side application development, are there interesting features for me in this release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ReleaseNotes) for Natty has just been released - it highlights the key features in the ubuntu server release.

As to "Is it worth to upgrade" - that depends on whether the new stuff is what you need.